# Can you use a subexpression within fold expressions?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, fold-expression

Is the following a legal fold expression?

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Ix>
bool in_range(std::index_sequence<Ix...>) {
  return ((Ix < N) && ...);
}
```

It compiles with [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CGqj7m5kWSGTt61V) but not [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/D8cEPQEr7x5ZiWIB)

Comment: I would think (without consulting official rules) `(A op ...)` is valid in that way whenever `A...` is valid. For example, `(Ix < N)...` being valid in some context would imply `((Ix < N) op ...)` being valid in some other context.

Comment: Incidentally, only right folds are affected by this bug. `(... && (Ix < N))` works on GCC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clang is doing the correct thing, the grammar from the [Folding expressions Proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4295.html) is as follows:

```
fold-expression:
      ( cast-expression fold-operator ... )
      ( ... fold-operator cast-expression )
      ( cast-expression fold-operator ... fold-operator cast-expression )
```

and contains the following wording that applies to this case (*emphasis mine*):

> An expression of the form (... op e) where op is a fold-operator is called a unary left fold. An expression of the form **(e op ...) where op is a fold-operator is called a unary right fold.** Unary left folds and unary right folds are collectively called unary folds. **In a unary fold, the cast-expression shall contain an unexpanded parameter pack.**

and `(Ix < N)` is indeed a cast-expression, so this looks valid. We can see the chain that gets us there, as follows from the grammar in section `5`:

```
cast-expression -> unary-expression -> postfix-expression -> 
 primary-expression -> (expression)
```

T.C. pointed out the following gcc bug report [[c++1z] "binary expression in operand of fold-expression" error when folding an expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68377) which reports a similar issue but it is still unconfirmed.

It looks like this is also broken in gcc for binary left and right folds, for example:

```
return ( (Ix < N) && ... &&  (N < 10) );
```

and:

```
return ( (N < 10) && ... &&  (Ix < N) );
```

Answer (score 4):

GCC is wrong. This is [bug 68377](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68377), presumably introduced by the fix for [bug 67810](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67810).

```
fold-expression:    
    ( cast-expression fold-operator ... )
    [...]

primary-expression:    
    [...]
    ( expression )
    [...]

postfix-expression:    
    primary-expression
    [...]

unary-expression:    
    postfix-expression
    [...]

cast-expression:
    unary-expression
    [...]
```

`(Ix < N)` is of the form `( expression )`, therefore it is a *primary-expression*, therefore it is a *postfix-expression*, therefore it is a *unary-expression*, therefore it is a *cast-expression*, therefore it can be used as an operand of a *fold-expression*.

Comment: Thanks. I actually put in [bug 68377](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68377), but was a little less sure after investigating more. But this looks like it answers it.