# declaration of void variable shadows template parameter in fold expression

Tags: c++, g++, operators, c++17, fold-expression

Is the following `g++`'s behaviour a bug?

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template< std::size_t ...i >
constexpr
bool f(int k, std::index_sequence< i... >)
{
    int j = (std::size_t((void(i), 1)) + ...) * k;
    return 0 < j;
}

static_assert(f(3, std::make_index_sequence< 3 >{}));
```

Gives an error message:

> main.cpp: In function `constexpr bool f(int, std::index_sequence<i ...>)`:
>
> main.cpp:11:33: error: declaration of `void i` shadows template parameter
>
> ```
> int j = (std::size_t((void(i), 1)) + ...) * k;
>                             ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:7:11: note: template parameter `i` declared here
>
> ```
> template< std::size_t ...i >
>           ^~~
> ```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e4bce903e9590d2)

Changing from `void` to `static_cast< void >` makes error to cease.

Multiplication by `k` from the left side also makes error to cease.

`std::size_t` here is to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748391/can-you-use-a-subexpression-within-fold-expressions) `g++`'s bug.

I know, that declaration `int (i),` is equivalent to `int i,` in a couple of contexts, but not in lhs part of built-in comma operator. Moreover, it is a `void` variable declaration.

Comment: Looks very strange for me.

Comment: Might be a GCC compiler bug. Declaration syntax is hard :-) Clang seems to be fine with the code. (I suppose that's why they say "1z support is *experimental*.)

Comment: GCC 7 isn't released.

Comment: @T.C. They coming from 6.x version and previous.

Comment: But yes, this looks like a bug. I don't see how that can be parsed as a declaration. I suspect that they were trying a type-id parse first (if you squint, the first part looks like a C-style cast), and somehow failed to gracefully recover when it discovered the conflict.

Comment: @T.C.: Also, C++17 isn't released, so no rush :-)

Comment: Reported as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78388